# Regex for splitting specific operators such as (^,*, >,<,<=,>=, +, -, !, $)?

Tags: java, regex, split

Trying to Create a Specific Method, that splits a formula into two arrays, an Array that holds the operators and the array that holds the numeric values.

Operators include: (^,*, >,<,<=,>=, +, -, !, $) 
Example:
String formula = "17−(23+4)*5$"

Im currently using the String split function. I used the regex ("\s*[^0-9]+\s*"); and its working for the valueArray.

If someone can let me know what regex I should use to split the operators listed above, that'd be amazing.

Comment: What about splitting on `[<>]=|[*^><+!$−-]`?

Comment: Getting the numeric values is easy with `\d+`. You can get all the other characters with `[^\d]+` (omit the `+` if you want to get each operator separately)

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. Just scan the string directly a character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the numeric values grouped as numbers you can use the regex:

```
(\s*\d+\s*)
```

Note that the `(` and `)` are part of the actual regex pattern itself.

To get the symbols you can use what is essentially just the inverse pattern

```
(\s*[^\d]\s*)
```

This would give you `[−, (, +, ), *]`. If you want the symbols grouped together then use

```
(\s*[^\d]\s*)
```

which will give you `[−(, +, )*]`.